# Resizable dialog window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mahapps.metro

I use MetroWindow class from Mahapps to show dialog window of some kind. 
My idea was to create auto resizable window, to fit it's content size

```
<controls:MetroWindow 
    ...
    DataContext="{Binding DialogVM, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
    Title="{Binding WindowHeader}"
    WindowTitleBrush="{StaticResource MainStyleTitleBrush}"
    Background="{StaticResource MainStyleBackgroundBrush}"
    wpfExtensions:SizeObserver.Observe="True"
    wpfExtensions:SizeObserver.ObservedWidth="{Binding xHeight, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
    wpfExtensions:SizeObserver.ObservedHeight="{Binding xWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
    MaxWidth="1110" MaxHeight="1080"
    MinWidth="450" MinHeight="600"
    ShowMinButton="False"
    ShowMaxRestoreButton="False"
    BorderThickness="1"
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource MainStyleBorderBrush}"
    SizeToContent="Width"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
      <ContentPresenter  Content="{Binding VM}"/>
    </Grid>  
</controls:MetroWindo>
```

but I have two issues 
First one: My window is affected to user actions (Mouse double click on title, drag window to left or right screen edge, and so on), and I want it to be frozen, but resizable.
Second one: when I reshow the same window again (without recreating it, but with new content which can have new visible size) it show's on it's last position.

How can I solve this problems without code-behind WindowSizeChanged event catching?

Comment: 1) You need to set `WindowStyle=None` that will 'Disable' window's title, but will leave it resizable.
2) Add a `Border` (filled with some color) with inner `Label` that'll be you 'Title'
3) You can use Window's properties [Top](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.window.top(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.window.left(v=vs.110).aspx) to store window's position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put ResizeMode="NoResize" and SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"